# Spring boot RESTful service: how to post an array of JSON?

Tags: arrays, json, spring

In my service, I have this class definition:

```
class SomeItem {
    private String item;
    private String[] tags;
    //gettter/setters
}
```

How can I post tags field (which is an array of JSON) to the service?

```
{ "item": "notebook", "tags": [{"type":"region","code":"nam", "name":"nam"}, 
{"type":"author", "code":"BBB", "name":"Alex"}]}
```

Comment: You can build another class with `type`, `code` and `name` properties. Then have `tags` be an array of that new class.

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrayList<JSONObject> arrayList = new ArrayList<JSONObject>();
JSONObject postedJSON = new JSONObject();

try {
    objJSON.put("key", "value");
  // add key value for json formating    
} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
arrayList.add(postedJSON);
String variable = arrayList.toString();
```